# How to determine if an executable was launched from within an active shell or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, cmd

I am writing some Python code that I finally pack into an executable (`myexec.exe`) with `pyinstaller`. This is a command-line program that may be launched

- from within a shell (`cmd` or `powershell` is running, and from within the user starts `myexec.exe`)
- or from another program (specifically AutoHotKey) as `myexec.exe`

I would like to be able to recognize which case I am in to end the program with an `input()` or not - the idea being that if it is launched from a shell it can exit immediately (the output will be visible in the shell), and if not then the window should remain for the user to see the output (and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit).

Is there a way to check for these cases from within Python?

Comment: can you try `getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` ? that would be True if file is frozen (an exe) based on that you can write branching for non frozen or frozen

Comment: @python_user: It will always be an executable, just started in different ways (I updated the question to make it more clear)

Comment: @WoJ : What shell are you refering to? POSIX shell? It's not that likely that you will use it on Windows.

Comment: @user1934428: I am not well versed in the Windows lingo. I am referring to the commands `cmd` or `powershell` that start a terminal, from which prompt I can start my executable `myexec.exe`(case 1 in my question). The second case is when `myexec.exe` is started non-interactively (though AutoHotKey in my case). Any update in the description to meke it more clear is welcome.

Comment: Please tag your question with _powershell_ or _cmd_, depending which one you want to use.

Comment: Just add some command-line flag (*-ah* for example) in AutoHotKey script and check if this key exist in your application with `sys.argv`

Comment: @viilpe: ah, this is a very good idea. Would you mind making it an answer?

Comment: @WoJ done. I am also making a Python version of AutoHotKey, you can see it in my github (link in profile).

Comment: @viilpe: *I am also making a Python version of AutoHotKey* - oh this is a great app! I will try to integrate it to my Home Assistant setup to automate some actions directly from the keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a command line argument when starting from AutoHotKey and you can check this argument inside the program like this:

```
import sys

if '--from_script' in sys.argv:
    print('launched from script')
```